# Can you `npm install` from Team Services git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, npm, azure-devops, npm-install

I can successfully

```
git clone https://[org].visualstudio.com/_git/[repo]
```

but if I run

```
npm install https://[org].visualstudio.com/_git/[repo] --save
```

I get

```
npm ERR! fetch failed https://[org].visualstudio.com/_git/[repo]  
npm WARN retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: fetch failed with status code 203
```

Is it possible to install npm packages from Team Services git repos like you can from github?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to install a package from a specific Git repo you need to structure the URL as follows, notice that the url is prepended with `git+https://`

`npm i --save git+https://[org].visualstudio.com/_git/[repo]`

This will also work if you want to install your repo over ssh

`npm i --save git+ssh://git@github.com:<owner>/<repo>`

You can add these style repo URL's to your `package.json` dependencies as well

```
"dependencies": {
  "custom-pkg": "git+https://[org].visualstudio.com/_git/[repo]"
}
```

You can read more about the different ways to install directly from git with npm in the [`npm install` docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Comment: If you use the "git+https" format, where do you specify the username and password?

Comment: I'm getting "error premature close" -- not sure this works with secured azure repos

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install a specific branch, you can run:

```
npm install git+https://[org]@dev.azure.com/[org]/Products/_git/[repo]#[branch]
```